# The length in the circle,PAM constellation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles, angle

The minimum distance of each point is $A$, and I don't know how to calculate the length of $b$, the solution said

$b^2=a^2+A^2-2aAcos(75)$,but i don't understand the reason about this formula, can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by when you say the minimum distance of each point is $A$? I assume you mean the distance between one of the four points on the inner circle and one of the two closest points on the outer circle is $A$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the cosine rule. In this case it tells you:
$$b^2=a^2+A^2-2aAcos(\alpha).$$

We're looking at the following triangle:
[image]

Now you only need to find the angle, and you're done.